# Changing <tr> bgcolor based on the count of <tr>'s present in HTML with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using multiple `<tr>` in HTML page with `bgcolor` values like:

```
<tr bgcolor="#000000">
<tr bgcolor="#E5F1CC">
<tr bgcolor="#D30A0A">
<tr bgcolor="#656766">
```

I need to give different background colors for all `<tr>`.

There are no classes nor ids used in HTML.

Without touching HTML, I need to give background colors in CSS for all  elements by specifying their numbers of count in HTML.

i.e I want to count the number of `<tr>` elements present in HTML and give different `bgcolors` for them.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This is supported in all major browsers [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/MM2SU/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width:100%;
}
tr {
    height:50px;
    background:#000000;
}
tr + tr {
    background:#E5F1CC;
}
tr + tr + tr {
    background:#D30A0A;
}
tr + tr + tr + tr {
    background:#656766;
}
```

2) we can also achieve that using CSS `:nth-child()` selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier. [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/8MNsY/1/) of `:nth-child()`

```
table {
    width:100%;
}
tr {
    height:50px;
    background:#000000;
}
tr:nth-child(2) {
    background:#E5F1CC;
}
tr:nth-child(3) {
    background:#D30A0A;
}
tr:nth-child(4) {
    background:#656766;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of rows is not know to you, you can use a javascript with something like

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var i=0; i<trs.length; i++){
    trs[i].style.backgroundColor = "#insertcolor";
}
```

If you however know the number of rows, look at css pseudo classes:

```
E:nth-child(n){
    background-color: #insertcolor
}
```

This is all pseudo code so there might be syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Simple CSS rules for different rows:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ffffff; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #000000; }
```

Or if you have multiple colors you can target specific rows the same way:

```
tr:nth-child(1) { background-color: #123456; }
tr:nth-child(2) { background-color: #654321; }
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can use a selector on the tr tags.

```
$("tr") or $("tr.specifyAClass")
```

then you can count the number of tr found :

```
$("tr").length
```

then you can loop over the array of tr and apply a color.

Comment: I dont want to use jquery please..I need it in css

Comment: ok as you put the javascript tab I thought it was an option. seems to me like slash197 answer is good. you can also not use jQuery and write a lot of javascript to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can add class name using jquery Addclass.Add the class name to table and get the tr using that class nae.
Then use jquery css property like $(tr).css('backgroundcolor','red');

Comment: I dont want to use jquery please..I need it in css

Comment: table tr:nth-child(odd) {}
  table tr:nth-child(even) {}

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, since you want to use `bgcolor` and don't want to touch the `HTML` ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6fbt5/)):

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'), i = 0, l = trs.length;
for(; i < l; i++)
{
    trs[i].setAttribute('bgcolor', '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6));
}
```

You asked for fixed colors so use following instead ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6fbt5/1/)) :

```
var colors = ['#ccddee','#123aaa','#fbfb11'];
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'), i = 0, l = trs.length;
for(; i < l; i++)
{
    trs[i].setAttribute('bgcolor', colors[i]);
}
```

Make sure to add more colors, three color requires for three rows. If you allow one color in multiple rows then you may [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/6fbt5/2/), so you don't have to add colors for each row.

Comment: No random color please..Want specific bg color